# Статический конструктор и ConstructorInfo

Tags: c#, ооп

Есть класс

```
public class A
{
  public A() { }
  static A() { Console.WriteLine("Call Static Constructor A"); }
  public static A CreateA(Type typeA)
  {
    System.Reflection.ConstructorInfo constructorInfo = typeA.GetConstructor(new Type[0]);
    Console.WriteLine("Call CreateA Constructor");
    A a = (A)constructorInfo.Invoke(new object[0]);
    return a;
  }
}

public class B : A
{
  static B() { Console.WriteLine("Call Static Constructor B"); }
  public B() : base() { Console.WriteLine("Call Constructor B"); }
}
```

Есть код

```
A a = A.CreateA(typeof(B));
```

Вывод в консоль

> Call Static Constructor A
>
> Call CreateA Constructor
>
> Call Static Constructor B
>
> Call Constructor B

Почему `Call CreateA Constructor` вызывается до `Call Static Constructor B` и как сделать так, чтобы при любом обращении к типу `B`, даже `typeof(B)` или `typeof(B).GetConstructor` вызывалось `static B()`<del>, а то получается что `public B() : base()` выполняется до `static B()`</del>

UPD: И возможно ли взять все типы классов наследованных от текущего класса?

---

UPD: Костыль вызывающий первое попавшееся статическое свойство у всех наследников класса `A` чтобы принудительно вызвать статический конструктор каждого из них...

```
static static A() {
  Type[] allAssignableTypes = (from domainAssembly in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
                               from assemblyType in domainAssembly.GetTypes()
                               where typeof(A).IsAssignableFrom(assemblyType)
                               select assemblyType).ToArray();
  foreach (Type type in allAssignableTypes)
  {
    PropertyInfo p = type.GetProperties().FirstOrDefault(x => x.GetMethod.IsStatic);
    if (p != null)
      p.GetValue(null);
  }
}
```

Comment: Вы делаете что-то странное - обычно, такой порядок вызова статических конструкторов и является правильным.

Comment: @PavelMayorov мне сложновато описывать логику взаимодействия классов. Мне было необходимо, чтобы все статические конструкторы зависимые от `A` были выполнены...

Comment: В общем случае это невозможно - ведь сборка, содержащая зависимый тип, может быть еще даже не загружена.

Comment: @PavelMayorov мой костыль сработал... Теперь при любом вызове чего-либо в классе `A` в статическом конструкторе вызываются все статические наследников, если в них есть статические свойства. В принципе то, что мне и нужно было

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> MSDN: [*A static constructor is called automatically to initialize the class before the first instance is created or any static members are referenced.*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/k9x6w0hc.aspx)

Это значит, что статический конструктор вызывается один раз перед первым созданием объекта класса, либо при обращении к статическим членам класса.

При вызове `typeof` не происходит ни того ни другого, поэтому статический конструктор и не вызывается.

> как сделать так, чтобы при любом обращении к типу *B*, даже `typeof(B)` или `typeof(B).GetConstructor` вызывалось `static B()`?

Судя по всему: никак.

Comment: т.е. единственный способ это принудительно создавать, например, синглтон и уже потом работать о классами?

Comment: @ДмитрийЧистик, можно обратиться к статическому свойству или создать объект. Пока не понимаю зачем это вообще нужно, возможно ты пытаешься закрутить отверткой гвоздь и для твоей настоящей задачи это совсем не надо

Comment: мне сложновато описать цель, которую я хочу добиться, но да, я закручиваю гвоздь отвёрткой... А можно ли получить все типы классов наследуемых от класса `A`?

Comment: @ДмитрийЧистик, на сколько я знаю - нет, можно только получить вообще все типы, и применяя [Type.IsAssignableFrom](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.type.isassignablefrom(v=vs.110).aspx) проверить можно ли объект указанного класса присвоить объекту проверяемого. Ну и [английский вопрос: _Get all derived types of a type_](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/857705/get-all-derived-types-of-a-type)

Answer (score 5):

Вызова `typeof(B)` недостаточно для срабатывания инициализации типа. Это поведение определено спецификацией C# (раздел 10.12), поэтому изменить его нельзя:

> The static constructor for a closed class type executes at most once
> in a given application domain. The execution  of a static constructor
> is triggered by the first of the following events to occur within an
> application domain:
>
> - An instance of the class type is created.
> - Any of the static members of the class type are referenced.